# Count loops through EMP_MGR hierarchy until MGR_ID = CO_ID

Tags: sql, loops, recursion, sql-server-2012, hierarchical-data

I have a question that I haven't been able to find a good answer for. It looks like recursion is the key, but there are some counts and ifs that I'm not sure how to implement. This is all in SQL Server 2012.

There are two tables and an M0 is an ID.

Table 1: EMP_MGR

```
EMP_Name | EMP_ID | EMP_Email | MGR_Name | MGR_ID | MGR_Email
```

Table 2: CO_SPOC

```
CO_Name | CO_M0 | CO_Email | SPOC | SPOC_M0 | SPOC_Email
```

The problem is that we need to have a loop that looks at an employee and manager as a step. That's 1 step. If the manager is the CO (not all managers are COs) then that is the top and the end. We want to count how many steps an employee is from the manager that is a CO. If that manager is not a CO, it loops through them and sees if their manager is the CO. The further down the ladder, the higher the step count.

```
EMP_M0     MGR_M0     CO_M0     Steps
   1          2        null       2
   2          3        null       1
   3          4         4         0
```

I used this join to build the EMP_M0, MGR_M0, CO_M0 table.

```
select EMP_MGR.EMP_M0, EMP_MGR.MGR_M0, CO_SPOC.CO_M0
       from EMP_MGR left join CO_SPOC
              on EMP_MGR.MGR_M0 = CO_SPOC.CO_M0
       order by EMP_MGR.EMP_M0
```

How can I loop through this to count the 'generations'? And then repeat that until MGR_M0 = CO_M0. Then repeat that throughout the set assigning descending values from the lowest employee having the highest number of steps and the MGR_M0 = CO_M0 = 0.

Thanks for any ideas or help!

EDIT:: Let me know if this won't work for sample data.

```
declare @EMP_MGR table(EMP_Name varchar(64), EMP_M0 varchar(64), Emp_Email varchar(64), MGR_Name varchar(64), MGR_M0 varchar(64), MGR_Email varchar(64))

insert into @EMP_MGR
values
('Jake','M01111','Jake@work.org','John','M01112','John@work.org'),
('John','M01112','John@work.org','Johny','M01113','Johny@work.org'),
('Johny','M01114','Johny@work.org','Jimmy','M01115','Jimmy@work.org'),
('Jimmy','M01115','Jimmy@work.org','Steve','M00111','Steve@work.org'),
('Steve','M00111','Steve@work.org',null,null, null),
('Joslin','M01216','Joslin@work.org','Jasmine','M01217','Jasmine@work.org'),
('Jasmine','M01217','Jasmine@work.org','Jane','M01319','Jane@work.org'),
('Jane','M01319','Jane@work.org','Steve','M00111','Steve@work.org'),
('Jana','M01419','Jana@work.org','Josh','M01420','Josh@work.org'),
('Josh','M01420','Josh@work.org','Steve','M00111','Steve@work.org'),
('Jessica','M01421','Jessica@work.org','Jerry','M01422','Jerry@work.org'),
('Jerry','M01422','Jerry@work.org','Jordon','M01423','Jordon@work.org'),
('Jordon','M01423','Jordon@work.org','Jay','M01424','Jay@work.org'),
('Jay','M01424','Jay@work.org','Steve','M00111','Steve@work.org')

declare @CO_SPOC table (CO_Name varchar(64), CO_M0 varchar(64), CO_Email varchar(64), SPOC varchar(64), SPOC_M0 varchar(64), SPOC_Email varchar(64))
insert into @CO_SPOC
values
('Jimmy','M01115','Jimmy@work.org','Frank','M01911','Frank@work.org'),
('Jane','M01319','Jane@work.org','Francine','M01984','Francine@work.org'),
('Josh','M01420','Josh@work.org','Frank','M01911','Frank@work.org'),
('Jay','M01424','Jay@work.org','Fred','M01943','Fred@work.org')
```

Comment: Sample data and result would help.

Comment: This is definitely achievable with recursive cte but sample data would be needed to get an exact query.

Comment: @Serg I've added some sample data for you guys. Thanks!

Comment: @scsimon I've added some sample data for you guys. Thanks!

Comment: this sample data doesn't fit your schema and thus recursion won't work on it. Populate the tables that you have shown the question.

Comment: @scsimon I think this should be some functional data. I've edited the post and replaced the data I had previously put.